# async Task running from vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-4.5

I have create class library in C#

```
static private async Task addMeeting(string subject, int roomId,bool coffee, bool receptionist, bool valetParking, string deductedFrom, string program)
{
await GetToken();
//some code with await
} 

static async Task<string> GetToken()
{
 //some code with await
}
```

Error while putting await 
[image]

Then I am referencing this class in **web application of vb.net** something like this

```
addMeeting("30 Minutes Booking",1,true,false,false,"","").GetAwaiter().GetResult()
```

But it never run and don't give any error too what I am doing wrong

Comment: In your vb.net web application, Did you try to make it `Await addMeeting(...)` instead of `addMeeting(...).GetAwaiter().GetResult()` ?

Comment: When I put await it gives error

Comment: Show us the error.

Comment: Updated question with error

Comment: `Await addMeeting(...)` not `Await addMeeting(...).GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. You may also need to mark the `Page_Load` as `Async`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved by putting await with parenthesis  after Await and Async Sub and page with  Async="true"

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="NewTemp.aspx.vb" Async="true" Inherits="MeetingRooms.NewTemp" %>
```

Then in Page_Load Sub

```
Protected Async Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Await (addMeeting("MPP Test By Milind with API", 1, False, True, False, "", ""))
  End Sub
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Actually, the parenthesis doesn't matter. `Await (addMeeting("MPP Test By Milind with API", 1, False, True, False, "", ""))` will be the same as `Await addMeeting("MPP Test By Milind with API", 1, False, True, False, "", "")`

Comment: And besides of your problem, Passing too much arguments to a method seems like a code smell to me. Better to encapsulate these in a class. (Keeping the code like that will make it a nightmare to be maintainable in future)